# Why Scala PartialFunction works without defining isDefinedAt?

Tags: scala, partialfunction, partial-functions

It looks **First** and **Second** are the same, but why?

First

```
val iter = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5).iterator
val first = iter.collect(new PartialFunction[Int, Int]{
  def apply(i: Int) = i
  def isDefinedAt(i: Int) = i > 0 && i < 3
})
first.foreach((println(_)))
```

Second

```
val iter2 = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5).iterator
val second = iter2.collect {
  case i:Int if i > 0 && i < 3 => i
}
second.foreach((println(_)))
```

Is it because the Scala compiler automatically converts 
`{ case i:Int if i > 0 && i < 3 => i }`  into the implelentation form of **First** with generating `isDefinedAt` from `if i > 0 && i < 3` part?

Also, `case i:Int if i > 0 && i < 3 => i` is Case class pattern matching, if I am correct. However, in [scala/src/library/scala/PartialFunction.scala](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.12.8/src/library/scala/PartialFunction.scala#L1), there is no Case class definition for `PartialFunction`.

```
trait PartialFunction[-A, +B] extends (A => B)
```

Then why this case class pattern match works?

I suppose Scala compiler does lots of implicit works intelligently but it confuses me to understand what is happening and how to write Scala code.

If there are good references, instead of language or compiler specifications, to understand 
 Scala code syntax and Scala way of writing code, please suggest.

Comment: No, pattern matching doesn't work only on case classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it because the Scala compiler automatically converts { case i:Int if i > 0 && i < 3 => i } into the implelentation form of First with generating isDefinedAt from **if i > 0 && i < 3 ** part?

Yes, the exact translation is given in [Pattern Matching Anonymous Functions](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/08-pattern-matching.html#pattern-matching-anonymous-functions). Here it'll be

```
new PartialFunction[Int, Int]{
  def apply(x: Int) = x match {
    case i:Int if i > 0 && i < 3 => i
  }
  def isDefinedAt(x: Int) = x match {
    case i:Int if i > 0 && i < 3 => true
    case _ => false
  } 
}
```

Note the difference with your first example in `apply`! You *can* still call it when `isDefined` is false.

> Also, case i:Int if i > 0 && i < 3 => i is Case class pattern matching, if I am correct

If anything, it's the other way around; case classes are called that way because they can be pattern-matched and pattern matching uses `case` keyword in Scala.

Comment: The spec is way out of date there, so I posted the exact translation. I'll create a ticket, as there is still plenty of time to update the spec for Scala 3, which doesn't have a spec yet. I'll also create ticket for a spec that is both up-to-date and that you can read for fun and profit.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the compiler converts the second version into a `PartialFunction[Int,Int]` (because that is what `collect` takes).

There is no `case class` matching here, and it is not even matching on type because the value must be `Int` (and therefore the type declaration in the second version is not required).

The [style guide](https://docs.scala-lang.org/style/) gives lots on tips on how Scala is typically written.

Answer (score 2):

For your example

```
object Main {
  def f = (1 to 5).collect { case i if i > 0 && i < 3 => i }
}
```

The compiler-generated partial function defines `applyOrElse` because it is more efficient than the naive idiom:

`if (pf.isDefinedAt(x)) pf.apply(x) else ???`

Showing that implementation, which is similar to what is described in the spec:

```
$ scalac -Vprint:typer pf.scala
[[syntax trees at end of                     typer]] // pf.scala
package <empty> {
  object Main extends scala.AnyRef {
    def <init>(): Main.type = {
      Main.super.<init>();
      ()
    };
    def f: IndexedSeq[Int] = scala.Predef.intWrapper(1).to(5).collect[Int](({
      @SerialVersionUID(value = 0) final <synthetic> class $anonfun extends scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction[Int,Int] with java.io.Serializable {
        def <init>(): <$anon: Int => Int> = {
          $anonfun.super.<init>();
          ()
        };
        final override def applyOrElse[A1 <: Int, B1 >: Int](x1: A1, default: A1 => B1): B1 = ((x1.asInstanceOf[Int]: Int): Int @unchecked) match {
          case (i @ _) if i.>(0).&&(i.<(3)) => i
          case (defaultCase$ @ _) => default.apply(x1)
        };
        final def isDefinedAt(x1: Int): Boolean = ((x1.asInstanceOf[Int]: Int): Int @unchecked) match {
          case (i @ _) if i.>(0).&&(i.<(3)) => true
          case (defaultCase$ @ _) => false
        }
      };
      new $anonfun()
    }: PartialFunction[Int,Int]))
  }
}
```

where `AbstractPartialFunction` defines

```
def apply(x: T1): R = applyOrElse(x, PartialFunction.empty)
```

Here is [an external link](https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/6799) to a change to use `applyOrElse`. The [improved PartialFunction](https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/342) dates back to 2012. Probably the feature is under-documented or under-advertised. Some information is available by expanding the [Scaladoc for `PartialFunction`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/PartialFunction.html#applyOrElse[A1%3C:A,B1%3E:B](x:A1,default:A1=%3EB1):B1). For some reason, that link shows `orElse`, so you'd actually have to scroll back for `applyOrElse`. It seems documentation is hard.